# Plot SVM hyperplane for 4 features

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, svm

How can I plot the hyperplane when the nfeatures chosen by the machine are 4? The code below is written for 2 features.

I get the following errors:

```
Error using classreg.learning.internal.numPredictorsCheck (line 29)
X data must have 4 columns.


Error in classreg.learning.classif.ClassificationModel/predict (line 396)
        classreg.learning.internal.numPredictorsCheck(X,...

Error in classreg.learning.classif.CompactClassificationSVM/predict (line 418)
            predict@classreg.learning.classif.ClassificationModel(this,X,varargin{:});
```

My code:

```
c = cvpartition(YTrain,'KFold',10);
%feature selection
opts=statset('display','iter')
%here it chooses by itself the best possible combinations of features to
%include in the classification model but taking into account the features
%we previously  specified
```

We did not specified the features so the machine will choose by itself the optimal features:

```
fun=@(train_data, train_labels, test_data, test_labels)...
sum(predict(fitcsvm(train_data, train_labels, 'KernelFunction','rbf'), test_data)~=test_labels)
[fs, history]=sequentialfs(fun, ZTrain, YTrain, 'cv', c, 'options', opts) %,'nfeatures',2)

%%best hyperparameters. 

%we select the only features that are useful for the model
XTrain_bestfeatures=ZTrain(:,fs);
Md1= fitcsvm(XTrain_bestfeatures,YTrain, 'KernelFunction', 'rbf',...
'OptimizeHyperParameters','auto',...
'HyperParameterOptimizationOptions', struct('AcquisitionFunctionName',...
'expected-improvement-plus','ShowPlots',true));

 %test the model
 XTest_bestfeatures=ZTest(:,fs);
 predictionsClass=(predict(Md1, XTest_bestfeatures) == YTest);
 Accuracy=(sum(predictionsClass)/length(YTest))*100;%predicts the belonging of an XTest instance to a 
 class

 %plotting the hyperplane
 figure;
 hgscatter=gscatter(XTrain_bestfeatures(:,1), XTrain_bestfeatures(:,2), YTrain);
 hold on;
 h_sv=plot(Md1.SupportVectors(:,1), Md1.SupportVectors(:,2), 'ko', 'markersize', 8);

 %plotting the decission hyperplane
 % decision plane
 XLIMs = get(gca,'xlim');
 YLIMs = get(gca,'ylim');
 [xi,yi] = meshgrid([XLIMs(1):0.01:XLIMs(2)],[YLIMs(1):0.01:YLIMs(2)]);
 dd = [xi(:), yi(:)];
 pred_mesh = predict(Md1, dd);
 redcolor = [1, 0.8, 0.8];
 bluecolor = [0.8, 0.8, 1];

 pos = find(pred_mesh == 1);
 h1 = plot(dd(pos,1),dd(pos,2),'s','color',redcolor,'Markersize',5,'MarkerEdgeColor',redcolor,'MarkerFaceColor',redcolor);
pos = find(pred_mesh == 2);
h2 =plot(dd(pos,1),dd(pos,2),'s','color',bluecolor,'Markersize',5,'MarkerEdgeColor',bluecolor,'MarkerFaceColor',bluecolor);



  uistack(h1,'bottom');
  uistack(h2,'bottom');
  legend([hgscatter;h_sv],{'class1','class2','support vectors'})
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update your post with the full error trace.

Comment: Edited. As far as I understood the machine chose 4 features for this data, but the representation code is made for 2 features. I want it for these 4 features.